# Issues while building Tabular Data Model from Vertica

Tags: azure, powerbi, data-modeling, vertica, ssas-tabular

I have been assigned a new project where I need to prepare a PowerBI report using Azure Analysis Services (Data mart). Here the flow is Data from Vertica DW -> Azure Analysis Services (via tabular Model)-> PowerBI. I am pretty much new to Tabular Model and Vertica

Scenario: 
1) The DW is in Vertica Platform online. 
2) I am trying to build a data model using Analysis Services Tabular Project in VS 2019
3) This model will be deployed on Azure which will act as data source to PowerBI
4) I cannot select individual tables directly (from Vertica) while performing "Import from Data Source". I have to use a view here. 
5) I have been given a single big table with around 30 columns as a source from Vertica

Concerns:
1) While importing data from Vertica, there is no option to "Transform" it as we used to have it in PowerBI Query Editor while importing data. 
However, I tried to import a local file and at this time, I could find this option

2) with reference to Scenario #5, how can I split the big table in various Dimensions in Model.bim? Currently, I am adding them as calculated tables. Is this optimal way or you guys can suggest something better?

Also, any good online material where I can get my hands dirty on modeling in Analysis Services Tabular Project (I can do it very well in PowerBI)?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to the 1st question, I believe there is some bug while connecting Vertica with PowerBI it works perfectly elsewhere except for this combination.

For #2, I can use I can choose "Import new tables" from the connected data source. It can be found under Tabular Editor View.

Answer (score 1):

My personal suggestion is to avoid using Visual Studio as hell. Unfortunately, it is not only useless but also damages you.

Instead, use [Tabular Editor](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/tabular-editor/). From there you can easily work with the Tabular Model.

My personal suggestion is to avoid using calculated table as dimensions, instead create several tables in Tabular Editor and simply modify the source query / fields.

Comment: Hi @Seymour,
Thanks for your reply. I am not able to retrieve list of tables from Vertica.
I entered the details and tested for connection and I got through but in the next step, it does not lists down the tables as a popup comes up with message 


"Unable to read list of tables/views from the source:
[Vertica][DSI][20032] Required setting 'Database' is not present in the connection settings."

Please can you advice further.

Comment: Hi @Seymour,
Also, what are disadvantages of creating calculated tables as dimensions?